# invalid block of form is rendered

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I want to show a form for invitation. I have created a form but when i go to the url /invitations/request, the invalid block is shown not the template with form. What might be the reason?

[image]

```
url(r'^request/$', requestInvitation, name='request-invitation'),

@csrf_exempt
def requestInvitation(request):
    form = InviteForm(request.POST or None)
    response_data = {}
    if form.is_valid():
        join = form.save(commit=False)
        email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        already_join, created = Invitation.objects.get_or_create(email=email)
        if created:
            already_join.invite_code = get_invite_code()
            already_join.save()
            response_data['result'] = "Thank you for your interest"
            response_data['email'] = email
            print ('response_data', response_data)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data),content_type="application/json")
    else:
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'result': 'Error message'}))
        # return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, 'invitation/invitation.html', context)

<form method="POST" class="invitation-form vcenter" action=".">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <div class="ui action input">
                <input type="email" class="requested_email" name="email" placeholder="Email address">
                <button class="ui button primary">Request Invite</button>
              </div>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to separate out the POST call. I mean, you need to check if the request method is POST or not. Something like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
  response_data = {}
    if form.is_valid():
      join = form.save(commit=False)
      email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
      already_join, created = Invitation.objects.get_or_create(email=email)
      if created:
        already_join.invite_code = get_invite_code()
        already_join.save()
        response_data['result'] = "Thank you for your interest"
        response_data['email'] = email
        print ('response_data', response_data)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data),content_type="application/json")
     else:
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'result': 'Error message'}))
    # return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

else:
  # An unbound form
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the workflow for your `request`:

1. A `GET` request is made (you're just visiting `/invitations/request`. So `request.POST` is an empty `{}`.
2. `form = InviteForm(request.POST or None)`. Thus, the `InviteForm` is not valid.
3. `if form.is_valid():` is `False`.
4. `else:    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'result': 'Error message'}))`. So, the `else` clause is executed, which returns a `JSON` response, which you're showing in your template.

Now, for the solution:

```
@csrf_exempt
def requestInvitation(request):
    form = InviteForm()
    response_data = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # This is a POST request, so request.POST will not be {}
        form = InviteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            join = form.save(commit=False)
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            already_join, created = Invitation.objects.get_or_create(email=email)
            if created:
                already_join.invite_code = get_invite_code()
                already_join.save()
                response_data['result'] = "Thank you for your interest"
                response_data['email'] = email
                print ('response_data', response_data)
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data),content_type="application/json")
        else:
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'result': 'Error message'}))

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'invitation/invitation.html', context)
```